# Limit number of characters in JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I try to limit the number of allowable characters to 5 by using

```
    try {
        jFormattedTextField2.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter("*****")));
    } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, when I only enter 1 character, there will always be 4 others space being padded. How can I avoid the padding, at the same time limiting number of characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`JFormattedTextField` leads to evil UIs.

The class you want is `javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter`. This allows you modify mutations in a chain-of-command style.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html has a section called "Implementing a Document Filter" that explains in more detail how to use a `DocumentFilter` to limit the length of a field, including source code for an example class, `DocumentSizeFilter`, that does just that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a JFormattedTextField, use a plain JTextField. Change the textfield's document to accept only a specific number of characters by setting a custom document.

Comment: A `DocumentListener` that rejects them??

Comment: @Tom: don't know what I was thinking there with the listener. I'll change my answer to just mention the custom document. That one is mentioned in the Java Text tutorial. I agree that DocumentFilter is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1):

Great question, and it's odd that the Swing toolkit doesn't include this functionality natively for JTextFields. But, here's a great answer from my Udemy.com course "Learn Java Like a Kid":

```
txtGuess = new JTextField();
txtGuess.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { 
        if (txtGuess.getText().length() >= 3 ) // limit textfield to 3 characters
            e.consume(); 
    }  
});
```

This limits the number of characters in a guessing game text field to 3 characters, by overriding the keyTyped event and checking to see if the textfield already has 3 characters - if so, you're "consuming" the key event (e) so that it doesn't get processed like normal.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: simple and perfect: it solved my problem (as I could not use other .getDocument() nor DocumentFilter solutions for various reasons) + I do not understand why anyone ever suggested this in dozens of other similar posts here on StackOverflow as it does exactly the simple thing one expects yet, extremely easy to implement, straightforward...